# Solo Trekking to Annapurna Base Camp

Tags: nepal, trekking

I would like to go to Annapurna Base Camp alone. 
Time : December 15 - December 24, 2017
I've few questions:

**Weather**: will the weather will be too much harsh on the that period? Will it be bit risky for solo trekking?  Please keep that in mind that I'm from a hot weather country. Temperature in my country is 30 in average.

**Security**: I guess on that period it'll very quiet. Is there any security risk like crime?

**Preparation**: I'm 28 and sporty. I frequently ride bikes and run sometimes. However I don't have that much experience for trekking like this magnitude. Should i take any more preparation? High altitude will cause problem?

**Suggestions**: Should I go with a agency? Actually I'm not people person. So I kinda like being alone.

Thanks all for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say this, but you should seriously consider signing up with a group for the trek. Your questions reveal a total lack of knowledge regarding mountain trekking and high altitude issues.

The altitude and potential for altitude sickness is enough reason unto itself.  One serious aspect of altitude sickness is confusion, so how will you save yourself if something like that occurs.  High altitude travel is always better done with others, keeping an eye on each other and helping as need arises.

The trekking, getting supplies, etc is something that perhaps with some training you can work through, but you need to consider that solo means carrying everything on your back that you need.

Comment: Honestly, at the ABC getting supplies is very easy. That is not the major issue here.